# Mongoose: How to get documents that their subdocument includes a value ( Many to one relationship )

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation that i need to filter users based on their Profession, here is how the User Schema is defined:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userData: {
      professions: [
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Profession'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

and here we have for Professions schema:

```
const ProfessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    }
  }
)
```

How can I get a list of users that have a profession with an id of `5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298` for example?

I tried

```
User.find({
    "userData.professions": { $elemMatch: $in: ["5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298"] }
})
```

But seems like this is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.
I need to get a result like this when I filter results based on `5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298` as id of profession

```
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "userData": {
            "professions": ["5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298", "5f8ea4226586f1168ab3a296"]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "userData": {
            "professions": ["5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298",]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Elon Musk",
        "userData": {
            "professions": ["5f8ea4466586f1168ab3a29a", "5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298", "5f8ea4146586f1168ab3a295"]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: The questions seems a bit unclear. Can you show sample data and expected output? What's wrong with the query you've pasted? Seems to be working fine: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3aP8cD3E3dE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert your professions id type string to object type using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`,
second you missed `{}` braces after `$elemMatch`,

```
let professions = ["5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298"];
professions = professions.map(profession => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(profession));
User.find({
  "userData.professions": { $elemMatch: { $in: professions } }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OSq2XQN9Sm5)

---

Second option, If you are matching single profession then this is alternative option,

```
let professions = "5f8ea4396586f1168ab3a298";
User.find({
  "userData.professions": professions }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZTY6e7o2pT4)